# cannot get mongodb connected with scrapy-linkedin

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, scrapy

```
Mon Oct 31 18:40:34 [initandlisten] fd limit hard:1024 soft:1024 max conn: 819
Mon Oct 31 18:40:34 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Mon Oct 31 18:40:34 BackgroundJob starting: snapshot
Mon Oct 31 18:40:34 BackgroundJob starting: ClientCursorMonitor
Mon Oct 31 18:40:34 BackgroundJob starting: PeriodicTask::Runner
Mon Oct 31 18:40:34 [websvr] fd limit hard:1024 soft:1024 max conn: 819
Mon Oct 31 18:40:34 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
```

the command prompt gets hung up for so much time as i start mongod.exe
i have made the directory data\db as well
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#mongodb-as-a-windows-service

Comment: And what is your question? Why do you write you start mongodb.exe by hand and give a link to running mongodb as a service?

Comment: i write the command in c prompt C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe

Comment: and then the above mentioned error comes it hungs up

Comment: I don't see an error. It is just telling you what it does and in the end waits for a process to connect on port 28017. So start your program in a second dos command window

Comment: thanks the issue got solved

Comment: @vikrocx consider sharing the answer for future generations.